# How to make a synchronous GET request with volley library? And how to parse it afterwards?

Tags: android, get, synchronous, android-volley

I've seen answer to both of these questions, however, when I tried to put them together, I couldn't make it work. The problem itself is pretty simple: I want to get a string from one site and use it in a post request. That means I can only make the post request after I've finished parsing the GET request. The main ideas I'm using are these ones:

[How to return response header field to main method using Google Volley for HTTP GET request in Android / Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137374/how-to-return-response-header-field-to-main-method-using-google-volley-for-http)

[Can I do a synchronous request with volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley?rq=1)

However the synchronous request is blocked and doesn't go on, and the first one is Async.

I believe this to be a simple thing to do, but still, I haven't be able to do it...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
// send first request
requestQueue.add(firstRequest, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            // ** code to parse response **

            // send second request
            requestQueue.add(secondRequest, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   // ** code to parse response **
                }
            }, new ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   // ** code to handle errors **
               }
            }));
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {          
           // ** code to handle errors **
       }
}));
```

Comment: Hey Itai Hanski. I though about doing that, but I didn't know if this is considered good practice. I said that because if I want to do many requests the code would became really strange and confusing. Also, I think I'll need this string later on. Anyway, I think I'll start with this and clean it up afterwards if there's better way. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! If my answer works for you, the good practice here is to accept it (that V next to it).